# how to add an element by clicking action in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm creating a simple logic here.
If one click an element from left-side box, the element will be deleted and added to right-box.
So, I create this functions

```
function deleteElement(e: any){
const clickedElement = e.target
  clickedElement.remove()
  const addedElement = <div onClick={addedItem}><input type="checkbox" className="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" /><label htmlFor="apple" className="fruit-name">Apple</label></div>
  const rightBox = document.getElementById("rightBox")
  rightBox?.appendChild(addedElement)
  console.log("The Element Has Been Added To Your Cart.");
}
```

but react/ts says

> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Node'.   Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following
> properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild,
> isConnected, and 46 more

So, type "Element" is not assignable to parameter of type 'node' ← this means appendChild is node system, right?
then How should I add any element in right-box??

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the children of the box as a state:

```js
const [boxChildren, setBoxChildren] = useState([]);

return (
    <div>
        {boxChildren}
    </div>
);
```

Then to add/delete on click (`element` is something like `<div></div>`):

```js
setBoxChildren([...boxChildren, element]); // .push

setBoxChildren([element, ...boxChildren]); // .unshift

setBoxChildren(boxChildren.slice(0, -1)); // .pop

setBoxChildren(boxChildren.slice(1)); // .shift
```

So for example, click the button to add elements:

```js
function App() {
  const [boxChildren, setBoxChildren] = React.useState([]);

  return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={
              () => setBoxChildren([...boxChildren, <div>hello</div>])
          }>add</button>
          {boxChildren}
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to not inject html in react in this way.

You should find a more react-compliant way like create a state variable and conditional render html:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function myComponent = () => {
   const [position, setPosition] = useState("left");

   const addedItem = (newPos) => {
       setPosition(newPos);
   } 
  
   return (
     <div>
        <LeftBox>{position === "left" && <div onClick={() => addedItem("right")}><input type="checkbox" className="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" /><label htmlFor="apple" className="fruit-name">Apple</label></div>}</LeftBox>
        <RightBox>{position === "right" && <div onClick={() => addedItem("left")}><input type="checkbox" className="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" /><label htmlFor="apple" className="fruit-name">Apple</label></div>}</RightBox>
     </div>
   );
}

export default myComponent;
```

In this example, every time you click div, checkbox will be rendered from an hypotetical component rendered on left side (I called it `LeftBox`) to another hypotetical component rendered on right side (I called it `RightBox`).